# How to convert multiple column to single row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query where in which i have to convert my dynamic column values into a sinle row

This is the query

```
select
    tblDefProducts.product_id AS Product_id, 
    tblDefProducts.item_name AS Product_name, 
    tblDefLineItems.field_name AS Line_name, 
    tblDefCategory.field_name As Category_name,
    DimRetailPrice.product_price AS Product_price,
    tblDefShops.shop_code AS Shop_code,
    (select SUM(NetQuantityMoved) 
     from StockMovmentFactTableNew 
     where StoreCode in ('whs') 
       and ReceiveShop = tblDefShops.shop_code 
       and ProductCode in (select ProductCode 
                           from DimCode 
                           where Product_Item_ID in (select Product_Item_ID 
                                                     from tblProductItem
                                                     where Product_ID = tblDefProducts.product_id))
    ) AS DISPATCH,
    (select SUM(NetQuantityMoved) 
     from StockMovmentFactTableNew 
     where TransType in ('SalesReturn', 'Sales') 
       and TimeStamp < '2016-10-09' 
       and StoreCode = tblDefShops.shop_code 
       and ProductCode in (select ProductCode 
                           from DimCode 
                           where Product_Item_ID in (select Product_Item_ID 
                                                     from tblProductItem 
                                                     where Product_ID = tblDefProducts.product_id))
    ) AS SALES,
    (select SUM(NetQuantityMoved)  
     from StockMovmentFactTableNew 
     where ProductCode in (select ProductCode 
                           from DimCode 
                           where Product_Item_ID in (select Product_Item_ID 
                                                     from tblProductItem 
                                                     where Product_ID = tblDefProducts.product_id)) 
       and TransType in ('SalesReturn', 'Sales') 
       and TimeStamp between DATEADD(day, -7, '2016-10-09') and  '2016-10-09' 
       and StoreCode = tblDefShops.shop_code) AS LAST_WEEK_SALE
from
    tblDefProducts, tblDefLineItems, tblDefCategory,
    DimRetailPrice, tblProductItem 
cross join 
    tblDefShops
where 
    tblDefProducts.line_item_id = tblDefLineItems.line_item_id
    and tblDefCategory.line_item_id = tblDefLineItems.line_item_id
    and tblProductItem.Product_ID = tblDefProducts.product_id
    and tblProductItem.Product_Item_ID = DimRetailPrice.product_item_id
    and tblDefCategory.category_id in (40)
    and tblDefProducts.product_id in( 3289 )
    and tblDefLineItems.line_item_id = 2
    and tblDefShops.shop_code in ('BGD' , 'DOL' , 'DMC' , 'GUL' ,'CGD')
Group by 
    tblDefProducts.product_id, tblDefProducts.item_name, 
    tblDefLineItems.field_name, tblDefCategory.field_name ,
    DimRetailPrice.product_price, Shop_code
```

Here the shopcodes are dynamic and so is the product_id.

The result will be in 5 rows having same product and with different sub query result. What i want is that it should be in a single line and results of my sub queries should concatenate one after another

Current output

```
   Product_id   Product_name        Line_name   Category_name               Product_price   Shop_code   DISPATCH    SALES   LAST_WEEK_SALE
    3289       The Butterfly Tree   Stitched    Shirts - Without Embroidery     2600        BGD             34      NULL        NULL
    3289       The Butterfly Tree   Stitched    Shirts - Without Embroidery     2600        CGD             NULL    NULL        NULL
    3289       The Butterfly Tree   Stitched    Shirts - Without Embroidery     2600        DMC             184     35          9
    3289       The Butterfly Tree   Stitched    Shirts - Without Embroidery     2600        DOL             187     24          6
    3289       The Butterfly Tree   Stitched    Shirts - Without Embroidery     2600        GUL             242     73          23
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: Can you post the current and desired output image or screenshots

Comment: No experience myself, but this seems the way to go: http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: 3289, The Butterfly Tree ,Stitched ,Shirts - Without Embroidery ,2600 ,BGD ,34 ,NULL ,NULL
3289, The Butterfly Tree ,Stitched ,Shirts - Without Embroidery ,2600 ,CGD ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL
3289, The Butterfly Tree ,Stitched ,Shirts - Without Embroidery ,2600 ,DMC ,184 ,35 ,9
3289, The Butterfly Tree ,Stitched ,Shirts - Without Embroidery ,2600 ,DOL ,187 ,24 ,6
3289, The Butterfly Tree ,Stitched ,Shirts - Without Embroidery ,2600 ,GUL ,242 ,73 ,23                                                                         This is current output

Comment: Google pivot sql server.

Comment: 3289, The Butterfly Tree ,Stitched ,Shirts - Without Embroidery ,2600  ,34 ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL,184 ,35 ,9,187 ,24 ,6,242 ,73 ,23                 and this is how i want a result

Comment: I have tried alot but didn't understand how it will apply in my situation

Comment: PLEASE post a image so that we can understand what is expected.

Comment: I have posted images in answer to this post

Comment: I have modified his desired out in question section.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #table(RefId INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,Id INT,Name VARCHAR(100),LName   
VARCHAR(100),Cat VARCHAR(100),Price INT,Code VARCHAR(100),Dis INT      
DEFAULT(0),SAl INT DEFAULT(0),LSal INT DEFAULT(0))
INSERT INTO #table(Id ,Name ,LName ,Cat ,Price ,Code ,Dis ,SAl ,LSal)
SELECT 3289,'The Butterfly Tree','Stitched','Shirts - Without     
Embroidery',2600    ,'BGD'  ,34 ,0  ,0  UNION ALL
SELECT 3289,'The Butterfly Tree','Stitched','Shirts - Without    
Embroidery',2600    ,'CGD'  ,0  ,0  ,0  UNION ALL
SELECT 3289,'The Butterfly Tree','Stitched','Shirts - Without  
Embroidery',2600    ,'DMC'  ,184    ,35 ,9  UNION ALL
SELECT 3289,'The Butterfly Tree','Stitched','Shirts - Without 
Embroidery',2600    ,'DOL'  ,187    ,24 ,6  UNION ALL
SELECT 3289,'The Butterfly Tree','Stitched','Shirts - Without 
Embroidery',2600    ,'GUL'  ,242    ,73 ,23

;WITH CTE AS
(  
  SELECT Id , CAST(Dis AS VARCHAR) + ',' +  CAST(SAl AS VARCHAR)+ ',' +     
  CAST(LSal AS VARCHAR) AS Comb
  FROM #table
)
SELECT DISTINCT Id , Name ,LName ,Cat ,Price,STUFF( ( SELECT ',' + Comb FROM    
CTE WHERE #table.Id = CTE.Id FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,' ')  
FROM #table
```

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit

Comment: First concat your DISPATCH ,SALES ,LAST_WEEK_SALES Values with use of CTE. Then use CTE table with your physical table and get result with use of stuff method

Comment: Thanks mansoor. But the requirement is that i need result in single SQL Query